# how to play an encrypted file in Android

Tags: android, encryption, media-player

I need to be able to play an encrypted file in Android.

The file is AAC.

The only way I can see to do this is either:

1. decrypt the file to internal private storage and point the player at that file to play, or
2. decrypt & decode the file to pcm and feed it to an AudioTrack.

1 isn't great because it takes a long time to do that.
2 isn't great either because I don't know how I can take advantage of the HW decoder to do this.

Any ideas?

tia.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an encryption format that can be decrypted on a stream, then you can insert a proxy between the stream source and the media player and read it from there.

The NPR Android News app has an example of a proxy inserted to allow pre-2.2 devices to properly handle Shoutcast streams. See the [StreamProxy class](https://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/browse/Npr/src/org/npr/android/news/StreamProxy.java) in the source code for how this is done and [lines 410-418 (as of last update) of the PlaybackService class](https://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/browse/Npr/src/org/npr/android/news/PlaybackService.java#416) for an implementation of that. It essentially just changed the URL to run through the local proxy server:

```
if (stream && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
  if (proxy == null) {
    proxy = new StreamProxy();
    proxy.init();
    proxy.start();
  }
  playUrl = String.format("http://127.0.0.1:%d/%s",
      proxy.getPort(), url);
}
```

If your stream comes from a local file, not the Internet, then you could do something like the [HttpRawResourceServer](https://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/browse/Npr_Test/src/org/npr/android/test/HttpRawResourceServer.java) that I wrote as a test harness to interface to the media player.

Comment: @Sivakumar thanks for the note. I've updated the links and included some of the relevant source code.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think Android does not support .AAC format.

```
 3GPP (.3gp) and MPEG-4 (.mp4, .m4a). No support for raw AAC (.aac)
```

but you could change the file
playerdriver.cpp inside the Android OpenCORE the following line::

```
mDataSource->SetDataSourceFormatType(PVMF_FORMAT_UNKNOWN);
```

to

```
mDataSource->SetDataSourceFormatType(PVMF_AACFF);
```

then you could play your AAC file =)

Comment: Note that this solution requires creating your own Android firmware.

Comment: sorry, I meant a .M4A file, the problem is not playing an unencrypted version, the problem is playing an encrypted version.  I need for the media player to take an InputStream.

Comment: creating your own Android firmware - ug.  seriously?  there's got to be a way to do it...  what about re-encrypting the file into a native DRM that the android system knows about?  is DRM basically out for android or what?  seems like a pretty severe limitation...